# Bios boot time 15 sec

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, raid-0

**My setup**:

- MotherBoard: Asus H170 Pro
- Bios Ver. 1803
- Windows 10

**Sata information**:

- SATA6G_1: ADATA SP900 (128.0GB)
- SATA6G_2: ADATA SP900 (128.0GB)
- SATA6G_3: N/A
- SATA6G_4: N/A
- SATA6G_5: N/A WDC WD10EZEX-08M2NA0 (1000.2GB)
- SATA6G_6: ATAPI iHAS224 Y ATAPI

SSD are in **raid 0**.

**Boot Priority:**

1. Windows Boot Manager (Intel Volume1)
2. SATA6G_6: ATAPI iHAS224 Y ATAPI

The problem is in bios boot time. It takes aprox 15+ sec. In my opinion it's very long. For example in my old, slow laptop with hdd it takes aprox 3 or 4 sec.

I show some img of my bios settings.

- [image: Boot settings]
- [image: Boot CSM settings]

It is possible to reduce my bios boot time to aprox 3 sec? and how do that?

Comment: Do you need that Comparability Support Module? What happens if you disable it? Did you display the fancy Logo and have a look what is actually taking so long?

Comment: Just a wild shot.... could you try unplugging all USB-devices during startup. Maybe only attach your keyboard and mouse but unplug all other devices. (I had lots of trouble staring up with a USB-harddisk attached once) Also... if you have a mem-check-during-startup setting somewhere in the BIOS, try disabling it.

Comment: @Seth I just do not know if i neet CSM. It is default enable. I display the fancy Logo but when i disable it the boot time do not decrease significantly.

Comment: @Rik
All USB-devices are unpluged.

Comment: With the logo disabled, do you see what exactly is taking so long? Option ROMs such as PXE boot come to mind.

Answer (score 0):

Please try disable this option "Advanced > PCH Storage Configuration > SMART Self Test".

Comment: Welcome to Super User! While this snippet may address the question, including an explanation of *how* and *why* this solves the problem [would really help](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

You probably do not have hibernation enabled. That means that the Kernel is shut down when windows shuts down which leads to it being reloaded every time and the boot time rises.

15 sec is not a problem its better to leave it like this because with the Kernel reloading every time Windows will work better and longer.

Comment: This topic is about BIOS boot time being 15s, not Windows boot time.

Comment: Sorry then, my mistake. In that case your BIOS loads something that is delaying it. Try reseting to the default settings, removing all CD and DVDs inside and all USB and external components connected to your computer.

Comment: All external components are always removed. I only removed cd but it not save any time.

Comment: What changes did you make during the period of the Bios starting to load slowly? It can not just do it by iteslf. Did you ask the vendor?